# Convert JSON data to BSON on the command line

Tags: json, mongodb, bson

I'm on an Ubuntu system, and I'm trying to write a testing framework that has to (among other things) compare the output of a `mongodump` command.  This command generates a bunch of BSON files, which I can compare.  However, for human readability, I'd like to convert these to nicely formatted JSON instead, which I can do using the provided `bsondump` command.  The issue is that this appears to be a one-way conversion.

While I can work around this if I absolutely need to, it would be alot easier if there was a way to convert back from JSON to BSON on the command line.  Does anyone know of a command line tool to do this?  Google seems to have come up dry.

Comment: I don't follow. What's the goal with the BSON file that you would create?

Comment: To then load back into the Mongo DB.

Essentially I want the following connectivity:

Mongo <-> BSON <-> JSON

I have 3 out of the 4 links required to make this work.

Comment: Why not just import it directly as JSON via `mongoimport`?

Comment: Honestly, didn't realize there were two sets of import/export tools here.  I'm still incredibly new to Mongo.  From the [mongoimport docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/), I read "... Do not use mongoimport and mongoexport for full instance, production backups because they will not reliably capture data type information. Use mongodump and mongorestore ..."  --  Not sure exactly what information is and isn't captured, but I think I'm going to play it safe and stick with importing the BSON dumps.  That way I know the test tests every single record in the DB.

Comment: I don't follow your comment, nor why you're trying to import data via the command line tools for testing. (Why are you trying to reimport data that was exported)? A JSON file cannot necessarily represent all of the data types of BSON adaquately for the purposes of an import.

Comment: The statement "A JSON file cannot necessarily represent all of the data types of BSON ..." pretty much answers my question.  I guess I just kind of assumed that they were an equivalent representation.  If they are not, I'm going to have to work with BSON exclusively then.  Is there any way I can close a question on StackOverflow without a specific answer provided?

Comment: Can you just close/delete the question? I've never had to do it, so I'm not sure... :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used them, but [bsontools](https://github.com/dwight/bsontools) can convert from json, xml, or csv

Answer (score 0):

As @WiredPrarie points out, the conversion from BSON to JSON is lossy, and it makes no sense to want to go back the other way.  Workarounds include using `mongoimport` instead of `mongorestore`, or just using the original BSON.  See the comments for more deails (adding this answer mainly so I can close the question)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [beesn](https://gitlab.com/monnef/beesn), it converts data both ways. For your variant - `JSON -> BSON` - use the `-x` switch.

Example:

```
$ beesn -x -i test-data/01.json -o my.bson
```

Disclaimer: I am an author of this tool.